# group_concat in sql server but concatination values column not in group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
S.No  Name  Path
1     a      a/b/c
2     b      x/y/z
3     a      a/b/c
4     c       t/y/z
5     b      x/y/z
```

in my sql to find repeated values

```
select Name,Path,Count(Name), group_concat(S.No) as Concatlist from tab 
group by Name, Path
OutPut will be 
a   a/b/c   2     1,3
b   x/y/z   2     2,5

c    t/y/z  1     4
```

Same query i want in ms sql server..

Please notice concatlist S.No column not using in group by....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string_agg()` in the more recent versions of SQL Server:

```
select name, path, count(*),
       string_agg(s_no order by s_no) as s_nos
from t
group by name, path;
```

Comment: I AM USING MSSQL SERVER 2014..PLS DO HELP AS PER ....

Comment: Simple searching will find many examples of string_agg alternatives for older versions of sql server.